# How can I read a comparison operator from a cell and use it in an If...Then...Else statement?

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched all over MSDN and couldn't find any info about this. I have a "Settings" sheet that controls my application. This sheet has a range of cells that store comparison operators such as <= and > for use in a procedure.

I have a list of fruits and a list of prices for how much each fruit was sold. I want to see how many apples have been sold for a price less than or equal to $10.

The previous version of my program used the WorksheetFunction.CountIfs method, and it basically read the operators from a worksheet into an array and used them like this:

```
Sub BuiltInCountIfsUsingArray()

    Dim rngOperator As Range
    Dim avOperator As Variant

    Set rngOperator = [A1:B1]

    avOperator = rngOperator

    With WorksheetFunction
        lResult = .CountIfs(rngFruits, _
            avOperator(1, 1) & "apple", _
            rngPrice, _
            avOperator(1, 2) & 10)
    End With

End Sub
```

avOperator(1,1) is read from A1, which contains =

avOperator(1,2) is read from B1, which contains <=

so in VBA,

avOperator(1,1) returns the value "="

avOperator(1,2) returns the value "<="

so therefore the above code is equivalent to:

```
Sub BuiltInCountIfs()

    With WorksheetFunction
        lResult = .CountIfs(rngFruits, _
            "=" & "apple", _
            rngPrice, _
            "<=" & 10)
    End With

End Sub
```

and the CountIfs function works fine with this.

My question is: how can I use the same kind of method of storing the comparison operators, but then using them in an If...Then...Else statement?

Basically, I want to go from this:

```
Sub MyCountIfs()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCounter As Long
    Dim lResult As Long

    For lRow = 1 To 10
        If rngFruits(lRow, 1) = "apple" _
            And rngPrices(lRow, 1) <= 10 Then

            lCounter = lCounter + 1

        End If
    Next lRow

    lResult = lCounter

End Sub
```

into something like this:

```
Sub MyCountIfsUsingArray()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCounter As Long
    Dim lResult As Long

    Dim rngOperator As Range
    Dim avOperator As Variant

    Set rngOperator = [A1:B1]

    avOperator = rngOperator

    For lRow = 1 To 10
        If rngFruits(lRow, 1) & avOperator(1, 1) & "apple" _
            And rngPrices(lRow, 1) & avOperator(1, 2) & 10 Then

            lCounter = lCounter + 1

        End If
    Next lRow

    lResult = lCounter

End Sub
```

if this is impossible with an array, reading the rngOperator directly would be good, too. Something like this maybe:

```
Sub MyCountIfsUsingRange()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCounter As Long
    Dim lResult As Long

    Dim rngOperator As Range
    Dim avOperator As Variant

    Set rngOperator = [A1:B1]

    For lRow = 1 To 10
        If rngFruits(lRow, 1) & rngOperator(1, 1) & "apple" _
            And rngPrices(lRow, 1) & rngOperator(1, 2) & 10 Then

            lCounter = lCounter + 1

        End If
    Next lRow

    lResult = lCounter

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just realized that using a function within the loop destroys the performance, so i'll just do a select case for each operator before the loop is run. thanks guys, i appreciate your time an effort and i learned something new today :)

i'm dumb, i forgot to mention that the first operator is always "=", so the user will only specify the second one.

```
Sub MyCountIfsUsingCases()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCounter As Long
    Dim lResult As Long

    Dim rngOperator As Range
    Dim avOperator As Variant

    Set rngOperator = [A1:B1]

    avOperator = rngOperator

    Select Case avOperator(1, 2)
        Case "<="
            For lRow = 1 To 10
                If rngFruits(lRow, 1) = "apple" _
                    And rngPrices(lRow, 1) <= 10 Then

                    lCounter = lCounter + 1

                End If
            Next lRow

        Case ">="
            For lRow = 1 To 10
                If rngFruits(lRow, 1) = "apple" _
                    And rngPrices(lRow, 1) >= 10 Then

                    lCounter = lCounter + 1

                End If
            Next lRow

        'Case "<", etc...

    End Select

    lResult = lCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe there's a mistyping in the second case :)... '<=' should be '>='

Comment: when you are happy with one of the answers you should accept it, even if its your own...

Answer (score 0):

If you included a reference to the Microsoft Access x.x Object Library, you could say:

```
    If Eval("'" & rngFruits(lRow, 1) & "'" & avOperator(1, 1) & "'apple' AND " _
         & rngPrices(lRow, 1) & avOperator(1, 2) & 10) Then
```

I am not sure why excel does not have `Eval`, but I am testing on an early version, so you may wish to check. Note that `Evaluate` is not the same thing at all. I am not at all sure that this is a good idea, but it is there, FWIW.

Comment: btw it was super easy too, i just enabled the Microsoft Access 12 Object library in the Tools->References... menu and then called the function by using Access.Application.Eval ("hello")

Comment: it was a great idea, but not for this purpose. thanks your your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function to do this

Something like

```
Function CompareTest(v1 As Variant, Operator As String, v2 As Variant) As Boolean
    Select Case Operator
        Case "=": CompareTest = v1 = v2
        Case "<>": CompareTest = v1 <> v2
        Case ">": CompareTest = v1 > v2
        Case ">=": CompareTest = v1 >= v2
        Case "<": CompareTest = v1 < v2
        Case "<=": CompareTest = v1 <= v2
        Case <insert any other operator you may need> 
        Case Else: <handle the invalid operator case as you see fit>
    End Select
End Function
```

Then your code becomes

```
For lRow = 1 To 10
    If CompareTest(rngFruits(lRow, 1), rngOperator(1, 1), "apple") And _
       CompareTest(rngPrices(lRow, 1), rngOperator(1, 2), 10) Then

        lCounter = lCounter + 1

    End If
Next lRow
```